# Given $n$, find $a$ and $b$ such that ${a \mod b = n}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's assume I am given a positive integer $n$, as well as an upper limit $L$.

How could one find all, or at least one, possible solutions for $a$ and $b$ such that ${a \mod b = n}$ where as $0 <=a, b <= L$?

Comment: When you say $a\mod b = n$, do you mean $a \equiv n \pmod b$?

Comment: I think that by $a\mod b$ he means the rest from division $a$ by $b$. This is common notation for that

Comment: @SamStreeter I meant that $n$ is the remainder of the division $a$ by $b$ just as Jakobian said.

Comment: @766F6964 What I have written means the same thing and is more standard notation in modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean $n$ to be the remainder of $\frac{a}{b}$, you could iterate over all $n< b \leq L$ and compute all $a = n+ kb$ for $k\geq 0$ and $a\leq L$.

Edit: here is a worked example. Suppose $n=2$ and $L=5$.

$a \mod b$ will be smaller than $b$, so we must start with $b>2$.

For $b=3$, we can try:
\begin{align}a = 2 + 0\cdot 3 = 2
\\a = 2+1\cdot 3 = 5\end{align}
and these are the only values of $a\leq 5$.

For $b=4$, $a=2+0
cdot 4 = 2$ is our only result and for $b=5$, $a=2+0\cdot 5 = 2$ is our only result.

This gives us solution set $\{(2,3), (5,3), (2,4), (2,5)\}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mind adding an example with small numbers, so that it is easier to follow your approach? Also, would this work too if $n=L$ ?

Comment: I added an example @766F6964 . $n=L$ would not work because $b\leq L$ and the remainder of $\frac{a}{b}$ is less than $b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your example is was able to understand everything. One more thing: Is there a formula to calculate how many combinations exist for $a$ and $b$ under $L$ without the need to calculate all of them until $b=L$ ?

Comment: Off the top of my head it should be $\sum_{b=n+1}^{L}(\lfloor\frac{a-n}{b}\rfloor+1)$

Answer (score 0):

For each $b \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\{a \in \mathbb{Z} : a \equiv n \pmod b\} = \{n+kb : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then note that $0 \leq n+kb \leq L$ iff $-\frac{n}{b} \leq k \leq \frac{L-n}{b}$.